# How to make the find string built-in method manually?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am still learning Python, but the instructor said that only using arithmetic, comparisons, procedures and if statements, you can make almost any program or built-in method and loops and other things can help you to make better code so I was wondering, how can you make the find string built-in method yourself (write a method that does the same work as the find method) only using indices, if statements and without using any built-in methods, this is what I tried to do:

```
def finder(target, search):

    if search == target:
        return len(target[:search])
    else:
        return '-1'
print (finder("test", "st"))
```

I know it has a lot of errors but this is the best I could come up with.

Comment: I believe he's referring to the built-in string method.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque find using index, comparisons, if statements, defined procedures and arithmetic, this is the  [video](https://youtu.be/MV9Q4BFa67A?t=451)

Comment: You should be more specific about what you want to do (e.g. the `find` function for the type `list` which returns ...), and you should show some effort of trying to do it (e.g. a block of code of what you've got so far).

Comment: without putting your attempt this question will be closed ... stack overflow wont do your homework for you ... if you need clarification on what the problem is you should ask the teacher

Comment: Do u want something like `"p" exists in "python" or not` type answer?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque I'd prefer if it was without any built-in methods.

Comment: `range( )` is a built-in method, is it allowed?

Comment: I am still in the beginning so, I don't know any built-in methods except find and max, and at this point, I'm supposed to be able to write something like this (this is not a problem in the course, I just thought of it since I am supposed to know enough to make it) so, range is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to search a letter in a word. How to do that:

Well, how should you approach?

Traverse through the word letter by letter and see any of them match with your desired one. Real simple.

One solution could be:

```
def finder(letter,word):
    for i in word:
        if i == letter
            return True
    return False
```

Test it with:

```
print finder("p","python")
```

Comment: What I meant is without using loops or built-in methods, but I guess it can't be solved without them so, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @MohamedMohey how do you traverse through the letters of the word if loop isn't allowed? Think about it.

Comment: after thinking about it, I think there is no other way, Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for a string in a given string, you can use `in` in Python. It would be more Pythonic way to do it.

```
def finder(givenString, searchString):
      return (searchString in givenString)

>>> finder("test","st")
True

>>> finder("bazinga","g")
True

>>> finder("smelly cat", "rat")
False
```